# Name of the following minimization $E[(X - c)^2] = Var(X) + (E[X] - c)^2$ with $c = E[X]$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, variance, expected-value

My professor proposed the below relationship as a property of the variance (he called $E[(X - c)^2]$ mean squared error):

$$
E[(X - c)^2] = Var(X) + (E[X] - c)^2
$$

and he said that, when $c = E[X]$, the mean squared error is minimized.

I'm wondering which is the name of this property/relationship.

Comment: This is the statistics version of Pythagoras' Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity you have is simply the [bias-variance decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Proof_of_variance_and_bias_relationship) of the mean squared error:
$$
E[(X - c)^2] = Var(X) + (E[X] - c)^2\quad (1),
$$

and it is proven quite simply by rearranging the identity for the variance
$$Var(Y)=E[Y^2]-(E[Y])^2$$

applied to the case $Y=X-c$.

Take $X$ as given and $c$ as a choice argument. Then it is clear from the right hand side of $(1)$ that since the variance term is independent of $c$ and the second term (bias squared) is nonnegative, the whole expression is minimized if you choose $c=E[X]$ (the bias term is then zero).

If you are interested in Bayes estimation, this is essentially the reasoning behind why any Bayes estimator under quadratic loss is just the [posterior mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator#Posterior_mean): it minimizes the posterior expected loss.

Comment: Hello @Golden_Ratio thank you very much for your helpful answer.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi no prob!